# Trouble with if statement

Tags: php

I'm a noob so please be patient 
I have to test an array, so that I check if it exists and to see if the numbers in it are ok.
In every case a message must be put out...for example...if the array is full and the numbers are ok I should get a message like (Array is full, Num are ok). But I use If after If and I get into trouble because.....well..take a look for yourself.

```
    public static function getTest($ids){       
        $input_result = array();
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $input_result['result']['Id '.$id] =  $id;
        }
        if((!empty($ids))){
            //echo "You have inputted some data in the Api_Books_Book::getTest<br/>";
            $input_success = "Successful!";
            $input_message = "Array OK";                                
        }
        else
        {
            //echo "There is no data<br/>";
            $input_success = "Not Successful";
            $input_message = "Have inputed anything in the array?";
        }              
        if(okNum($ids)) {
            //echo "You have inputted some data in the Api_Books_Book::getTest<br/>";
            $input_success = "Successful!";
            $input_message = "numbers OK";
        }
        else {
            //echo "There is no data<br/>";
            $input_success = "Not Successful";
            $input_message = "numbers not OK";
        }
        $result=array('status'=>$input_success,'message'=>$input_message,'result'=> $input_result);

        rdie($result);
        return $result;
   }
```

Comment: thank you for the minus...can you at least explain what I did wrong?

Comment: What errors/unexpected result to you get with the code above? (not my -1)

Comment: The thing is when I leave the array empty...it still gives me the message that everythings ok... "Successfull"...and that the numbers are OK...I would like to get the message...have you put something in the array.

Comment: Can you post the output that you are getting?

Comment: @ReneB See my answer. It looks like okNum returns true even if the array is empty and this overwrites the values of $input_success and $input_message. Have a look at okNum and consider reorganising your code.

Comment: what exactly the okNum method do? because your first if-else conditions are correct. Second set of if-else conditions works on the return of okNum, so what kind of return and logic the okNum method has.

Comment: okNum....well all it does is check if the number is "regular" in a sense 0,1,2,3,4,5    No decimals and no minus numbers and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if((!empty($ids))){
        //echo "You have inputted some data in the Api_Books_Book::getTest<br/>";
        $input_success = "Successful!";
        $input_message = "Array OK";                                
        }
        {
        //echo "There is no data<br/>";
        $input_success = "Not Successful";
        $input_message = "Have inputed anything in the array?";
        }
```

This looks like your problem (although you haven't actually told us what issue you are getting).
The above isn't an else so the "Not Successful" code will always run.

You should note also that the result of the if(okNum($ids)) will wipe whatever value you previously set $input_success to.

It's hard to say without seeing the okNum method but it looks like this returns true if the array is empty.

Comment: @ReneB It depends what kind of output you want. If you want to simply return if it's not ok you can return that in the if. If you want an array of all success and messages you should add that to an array which is returned at the end.

Answer (score 1):

On first glance you appear to be missing an `else` just before this code:

```
    {
        //echo "There is no data<br/>";
        $input_success = "Not Successful";
        $input_message = "Have inputed anything in the array?";
    }
```